# Birational $\mathbb{P}^{1}$-bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X_{1},X_{2}$ are smooth complex projective varieties, with rank $2$ vector bundles $E_{i} \rightarrow X_{i}$. Suppose furthermore $X_{1}$ is birational to $X_{2}$.

**Question:** Is $\mathbb{P}(E_{1})$ birational to $\mathbb{P}(E_{2})$?

If so is there a way to "see" the birational map between these varieties?

$(k=\mathbb{C}).$

Comment: For any variety $X$ and a vector bundle $E$ of rank $n$, $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}\times X$ and so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Thanks!, how to see it?

Comment: Any vector bundle is locally trivial. So choose an open in $X$ over which $E$ trivializes.